# Cannot bind string value in Doctrine DBAL using bindValue, Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, doctrine, quotes, dbal, doctrine-orm-postgres

I'm trying to use Doctrine DBAL in my project; my database is Postgresql.
This is a simple use case and I really do not know why is this not working.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field :order LIMIT :amount";
```

Let's assume that:

```
$order = 'DESC' and $amount = 'ALL';
```

The code above seems to be fine.

```
$statement = $app['db']->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue('order', $order);
$statement->bindValue('amount', $amount);
$statement->execute();
```

I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field $1 LIMIT $2
```

Could someone explain this behaviour? I'm suspecting quoting problem...

Best Regrards
Kamil

Comment: $stmtement->bindValue('limit', $limit, \PDO::PARAM_INT);

Answer (score 2):

Might you be missing a coma?

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field, :order LIMIT :amount
```

(Btw, you should really use emulated prepared statements for stuff like this. By not doing so, the order by/limit clauses basically guarantee that you'll end up with seq scans all over the place.)

Comment: Uhm, Thank You, I missed the coma...  
 And then 'ALL' should be null and everything works. I'll read about sequential scans, the subject seems to be not simple (and I never though of that before).  
 Thanks!

Comment: Hey, not working... This is something more fundamental. I'm using SILEX and tried QueryBuilder of Doctrine instead of above code:
    `$builder = $app['db']->createQueryBuilder();
    $builder->select('*')  
    ->from('news')
    ->orderBy('created_on', $builder->createNamedParameter($order))
    ->setMaxResults(20);
     $builder->execute();`  And it's not working too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured this out.

Part of an SQL language cannot be used as a parameter in prepared statement.
So one should use some kind of conditional for example to create such query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY field ';
if ($order = 'ASC') {
  $sql .= 'ASC ';
} else ... {
  ...
}
$sql .= 'LIMIT :amount';
```

Now everything should work.
And the parameter after the coma were treated as a parameter common to all queries and did not work. It could be everything and it had no impact on results.
I think the thread can be closed...